# Gradle Sonar Plugin Not Scanning Root Project

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Here's my project structure:

```
../project
    /submodule1
    /submodule2
    /src
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

Here's how I'm including the submodules using the `settings.gradle` file:

```
rootProject.name = 'rootProjectName'
include ':submodule1', ':submodule2'
```

Here's the properties I'm setting up sonarqube in the `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.profile", "Sonar Profile"
        property "sonar.projectName", rootProject.name
        property "sonar.projectKey", "KEY${rootProject.name}"
    }
}
```

And how I'm including the submodules in the root project:

```
dependencies {
    ..
    compile project(":submodule1")
    compile project(":submodule2")
}
```

But the soanrqube report is only showing results from analyzing the submodules, which ends up to be only ~100 lines of code when it should be much larger. I'm not sure what's wrong...

Comment: Can you precise your version of SonarQube (server)?

Comment: Sonarqube Version 5.6.6

Answer (score 1):

The support of modules having both source code and submodules was added in SonarQube 6.4:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6724